# How to rename multiple files in a folder using python script

Tags: python, file, rename

Say I have a folder with some files in it.

Name of the files are `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, .... ,` etc.

Can you help me write a script that will rename all the files to file abc1.txt, bcd2.txt, cde3.txt, .... , etc. ?

Names of the files don't matter. I just want to see the code.

Also, I HAVE NO KNOWLEDGE OF CODING. I just want to see how someone would do it.

Comment: import os then os.rename()

Comment: Hi, thanks Vicrobot. Can you elaborate it a bit in a step by step fashion ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.rename('xyz.txt', 'new_name.txt')
```

Just take care of the file-path.

Let we consider that you are running the python program in that same directory then do this:-

```
import os
var1 = os.listdir()  # takes all file's name in a list
var0 = 0
for i in var1:
    os.rename(i, 'file{}'.format(var0))
    var0 += 1
# new names would be file1, file2 ...
```

PS: Always experiment on a dummy folder first; so that there would be no chance of loss.